# AKS RBAC - Rolebinding has no effect

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-rbac

I'm setting up RBAC in my AKS cluster which is integrated with Azure AD following the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-ad-rbac?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Faks%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json). I have created an AD group in my AAD tenant, added a user to it. Then the group is assigned "Cluster User role" in the AKS cluster as per the instructions. Created a Role and Rolebinding as shown below:

Role:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: development
  name: restricted-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] 
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

RoleBinding:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-pods
  namespace: development
subjects:
- kind: Group
  name: 308f50cb-e05a-4340-99d4-xxxxxxxb 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  namespace: development
roleRef:
  kind: Role 
  name: restricted-role 
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

I then tried login using the new user credentials:

```
az login --username kubeuser@xxx.onmicrosoft.com --password xxxx

az aks get-credentials --name mycluster --resource-group myrg --overwrite-existing
```

As per the documentation, I should be only allowed to do kubectl get pods on the development namespace. However, using this new user credentials, I see that I can do kubectl get pods --all-namespaces, kubectl get svc --all-namespaces etc. and view the results, as if the Rolebinding does not have any impact at all. I also have verified by [checking](https://resources.azure.com/) that my cluster has

> "enableRBAC": true

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with this configuration?

Comment: what kind of `kubeconfig` file you get after the last command? Does it contain a section like:


  user:
    auth-provider:
      config:
        apiserver-id: <appserverid>
        client-id: <clientid>
        environment: AzurePublicCloud
        tenant-id: <tenant>
      name: azure

Comment: No. My kube config has api version, cluster, certificate-authority-data, server, name, contexts, namespace and users

Comment: then it seems your cluster is not AAD-enabled. Can you run the command:

az aks show -g <rg> -n <clusterName> --query aadProfile

Comment: thanks, for some reason my AAD integration wasn't correctly set. I did a reset and then it started working. Thank you

Comment: Well, you can add an answer to display the solution for the communities who are looking for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the command:

```
az aks show -g <rg> -n <clusterName> --query aadProfile
```

you can confirm if the cluster has Azure Active Directory enabled. If so, the `kubeconfig` file you get from the following command:

```
az aks get-credentials -g <rg_name> -n <aks_name>
```

should look like:

```
user:
  auth-provider:
    config:
      apiserver-id: <appserverid>
      client-id: <clientid>
      environment: AzurePublicCloud
      tenant-id: <tenant>
    name: azure
```